# Should I add only 2 nameservers?

Tags: azure, nameserver, digital-ocean

My servers were hosted on Azure and now I’m changing to DigitalOcean, so I also need to change the IP my domain points at, to the new server’s.

I have configured everything I need DigitalOcean-side and all I have to do now, is to change the old nameservers to the DigitalOcean’s. I realised that Domain.com, that’s where my domain is hosted, offers me 2 available nameserver slots, whereas DigitalOcean gives me 3 nameservers.

I contacted their support and told me than maybe Azure can help me out... now I’m waiting for their response.

Would it be a problem if I only added 2 nameservers out of 3?

Comment: Surely you can add more than 2 nameservers? Are you sure you are not just misunderstanding their UI?

Comment: I've looked and looked and there must be no way! See for yourself: http://prntscr.com/l14cqu

Comment: Seems strange. Also their documentation (which one cannot link to here but which resides at `www.domain.com/help/article/domain-management-how-to-update-nameservers`) has an "Add More" button, but the design is quite different.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist They recently updated their site and it seems no longer possible...

Comment: I wonder why you would _need_ more than two name servers.

Comment: @Tom Depends on the nature of the available servers; how are the different nameservers hosted (is it actually two servers or anycast with a bunch of nodes?), who operates them (same or different?), etc. Seems like a separate question, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue!

They updated their control panel and in this new version, you can't add more than 2 nameservers! However, I too chatted with their live support and the technical assistant managed to change the nameservers for me!

He also gave me this link: https://www1.domain.com/controlpanel/domaincentral/3.0
It seems you can change it from there yourself!

Hope this helps!